# Schedule in for loop

Tags: python, schedule

I have been trying to schedule actions in Python, using a for loop to iterate through an SQL query. I only get scheduled the last iteration.

```
con = mdb.connect(dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, dbname)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM `jobs`""")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    status = row[1]
    names = row[2]
    script = row[3]
    times = row[4]
    output = row[5]
    output_s = row[6]
    print(names, status, output_s)
    def job():
        if status == 1 and output_s == 1:
                system = os.popen(script) 
                system_output = system.read()
                print(system_output)
                cur.execute("""UPDATE jobs SET output = %s WHERE `name` = %s""", [system_output, names])
                con.commit()
        elif status == 1 and output_s == 0:
                system = os.popen(script) 
                cur.execute("""UPDATE jobs SET output = "Output Disabled" WHERE `name` = %s""", [names])
                con.commit()
                print('output disabled')
        else:
            print('job disabled') 
schedule.every(times).seconds.do(job)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just indent `schedule.every(times).seconds.do(job)` to be in the for loop.

Currently it is outside the for loop (see that it isn't indented like the other lines in the loop), so it is only ran after the loop finishes all iterations.

Comment: Doing this also schedules only the last iteration, but the job runs every second because of the while loop

Comment: If while loop is included in for loop the iteration stops at first element because "while True"